# I need to view the saved WiFi passwords on my non-rooted Android phone

Tags: wifi-password

I have an LG Optimus 7 (not-rooted), and all my WiFi passwords are there. I want to view the saved WiFi passwords to transfer thm to my new Samsung Galaxy S3, but I don't know how.

I tried to search on the Internet and Google play for an application that would allow me to view this information, but I can't find one. Is there any way for me to accomplish this?

Comment: That's not directly possible without compromising the security (aka. rooting), at least not via an app. Imagine an app to send your wifi passphrases elsewhere (besides showing you them).

Comment: (for others finding this via google) On MIUI there is a "tap here to share password" button in the WiFi settings. It shows a QR code that can be scanned with an app on another phone where it then shows the SSID and password.

Answer (score 4):

This is not directly possible (as noted in the comment below your question).

You can let Google save them to their cloud:

Go to: *Settings->Privacy* and enable those two options:

- Back up my data (Back up application data, **Wi-Fi passwords**, [...])
- Automatic restore

Also, say yes when you're prompted if you want to *Restore data* during the first time set up of your new SGS3. If you've done the first time setup already withouth that option enabled, then maybe the *Automatic Restore* settings does it afterwards (not tried yet, though).

Answer (score 1):

For an application to access WiFi credentials without root access, that app must be granted the permission [*android.permission.READ_WIFI_CREDENTIAL*](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#L1187). That permission, however, requires an app to be a [privileged or system level](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel) (part of Android image) app. If an app in your Android satisfies these conditions then you can ask its developer to add the potential functionality of revealing WiFi credentials to primary user through an update, as otherwise, I see no other way to view passwords without superuser access.