# How to show wi-fi password without rooting your phone?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola-moto-g

I have read [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66039/how-to-show-wifi-password) post, showing how to retrieve the stored wi-fi passwords. But I am not able to access the file.
And I have also enabled android backup settings for data. I think it also saves wi-fi passwords. But I don't know from which site I can access my android personal data.

I have recently purchased a new mobile and rooting will void the warranty.

Any idea how to retrieve without rooting.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: AFAIK, you need root to get access to the file which saved your WiFi password.

Comment: @AndrewT. Link updated

Comment: @AndrewT. Any other method without rooting ??

Comment: The file is protected in internal storage, so it needs root. Sorry, I don't know other method beside that. You could wait for others' opinion though.

Comment: Well, I don't think there's any method to get the wifi passwords without rooting as I remember that once over here I was also looking for the same and in the end the result is not you can't get yourself show the WiFi passwords stored in the device until or unless you root your device.

Comment: @PeterCarlos the answer provided in [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/i-need-to-view-the-saved-wifi-passwords-on-my-non-rooted-android-phone) question is not working for me.

Comment: @VarunChakervarti-Veer I am not referring to the answer rather than I am referring to the post where Ce4 has said "That's not directly possible without compromising the security (aka. rooting), at least not via an app. Imagine an app to send your wifi passphrases elsewhere (besides showing you them)."

Comment: @PeterCarlos And can I access my android personal data (back up data) which is saved on google cloud from any google products.

Comment: @VarunChakervarti-Veer Well, if the google product allows then yes you can but I would like to know more over here's which Google product you are referring to ??

Comment: @PeterCarlos Like we can access our contacts from gmail. Is there any products through which we can access our data.